# $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ which is surjective but not injective

Tags: functions, integers, natural-numbers

I'm looking for a really simple example of $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}$ which is surjective but not injective. I thought about:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x=0\\
\frac{x+1}{2} & x\text{ is odd}\\
-\frac{x}{2} & x\text{ is even}\wedge x\neq0
\end{cases}
$$
Is there a better and more simple  example I can use?

Comment: I think your function is injective.

Answer (score 3):

You can take, for instance, $f(n)=(-1)^n\left\lfloor\dfrac n2\right\rfloor$ (assuming, as you did, that $0\in\Bbb N$).

Comment: $(-1)^n\lfloor\frac n3\rfloor $ and $(-1)^n\lfloor\frac12\sqrt n\rfloor$ work whether or not $0\in\Bbb N$ and are "even more" non-injective

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sure. If someone had asked me how to modify my example if $0\notin\Bbb N$, I would have said $(-1)^n\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor$, but those suggestions are even better.

Comment: I see, I'll go with $f(n)=(-1)^n\lfloor\frac n3\rfloor$ as I use $0\not\in\Bbb N$. But why its surjective?

Comment: ... or $\sqrt n\lfloor \sin\sqrt n\rfloor$ would be as non-oinjective as can be, i.e., every integer as infinitely many preimages. Then again, the OP asked for a something *simple*.

Comment: @vesii In your example you wrote that $f(0)=0$. Why do you say now that, for you, $0\notin\Bbb N$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I actually wrote it due to other reasons but now that I think you are right, it should not be $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @vesii If $n\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$, then$$n=\begin{cases}f(3n)&\text{ if $n$ is even}\\f(3n+1)&\text{ if $n$ is odd.}\end{cases}$$The case in which $n<0$ is similar.

Answer (score 0):

$0 \notin \mathbb{N}$.

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be a surjective and injective function. Define:

$$g(n) = \cases {f(1),\quad n =1\\
                 f(1),\quad n =2\\
                 f(n-1),\quad n\geq3}$$

Then $g:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is surjective but not injective.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x=0\\
\frac{x+1}{2} & x\text{ is odd}\\
-\frac{x}{2} & x\text{ is even}\wedge x\neq0
\end{cases}
\implies
f(n)=(-1)^{n+1}\bigg\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2} \bigg\rfloor
$$

$$
f(0)=(-1)^1\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\bigg\rfloor=0\quad 
f(1)=(-1)^2\bigg\lfloor\frac{2}{2}\bigg\rfloor=1\quad 
f(2)=(-1)^3\bigg\lfloor\frac{3}{2}\bigg\rfloor=-1\\
f(3)=(-1)^4\bigg\lfloor\frac{4}{2}\bigg\rfloor=2\quad 
f(4)=(-1)^5\bigg\lfloor\frac{5}{2}\bigg\rfloor=-2\quad 
f(5)=(-1)^6\bigg\lfloor\frac{6}{2}\bigg\rfloor = 3$$

Of course, the following alone also meets the criteria: $$f(x)=(-1)^x$$

as does the floor function alone unless you talk about infinities.